# can not able to rechange the domain name path after changing in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.8

I renamed "base url " and "unsecure base url" in magento admin panel.

now i cant able to change it. even i changed value in core_config_data => base url and unsecure base url.

whenever i tried for http://whiteboardsnz.com , its redirecting to http://whiteboardsnz.co.nz/

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Comment: delete cache folder from var

Comment: hi, we did merging js and cs files, now it's displaying like this : http://whiteboardsnz.com/boards/ , please help me to find the solution

Comment: why admin page is displaying like this: http://boards.newtrendzonline.comindex.php/admin/?SID=da45b98290cc64365858c071956fcac9 but http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/downloader is working.

Comment: need to change all secure and unsecure url  to http://whiteboardsnz.com.for exemple.... for check js secure url change it( http://whiteboardsnz.com/js//)

Comment: magento secure/unsecure   url should need end with /(http://whiteboardsnz.com//)

Comment: {{unsecure_base_url}}media/ is like this = > http://whiteboardsnz.com/media , am i right?

Comment: i tell you every setting  end with a slash

Comment: check this http://postimg.org/image/pnaxq91yf/

Comment: hi check now : whiteboardsnz.com/boards , its redirecting to http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/

Comment: i did everything what you said

Comment: it is submoain setting,which is managed by hostig provider./boards folder is assign as sroot dir of submaion boards.newtrendzonline.com

Comment: okay, what i have to do now?

Comment: whiteboardsnz.com/boards change by  boards.newtrendzonline.com or remove subdoamian

Comment: we merged css and js files before, is it problem for this, the site is not displaying properly?

Comment: hi, check this link and please help me : http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/ why the site id displaying like this....

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, again i copied sub domain folder to main domain folder. i created new db copied again all backup databse files. you saved my lifez, thanks again....

Comment: hi, please post answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Baby in Magento question  and chat there are lot of issue:

**1)** `Base secure and unsecure  url is not end with slash`.It was `http://whiteboardsnz.com` it should be  `http://whiteboardsnz.com/`

**2)** `Magento system was at it subdirectory of whiteboardsnz.com  at boards folder`.Base secure and secure has been changed according to it.`But this folder is pointed  at sub domain so whiteboardsnz.com/boards change by boards.newtrendzonline.com`